# Where can I find some dummy data to teach my friend how to use a spreadsheet?

Tags: spreadsheet

In particular, tabular data that can be graphed.  What's your favorite source of interesting data?

Comment: Just use the spreadsheet you use when scheduling time with her.

Comment: @é_ho You use one too?

Comment: This is a FAQ: (see e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101960)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a huge amount of real world data freely available on various EU websites, such as [Eurostat](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/eurostat/home/).  All can be exported as .xls or .xml.

Most national governments will have some similar statistics portal, although some require login/subscription for the raw data.

Answer (score 2):

Why not you just use the sample files located in under **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\Samples** directory?

They are sample data from a fictional company called "Northwind", and are designed to simulate real company data that can be used to teach Excel tricks.

Comment: Good to know. Any idea if something like this exists for OpenOffice?

Comment: But I am not using that spread sheet software, and have no `C:`

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.generatedata.com/#generator

Answer (score 1):

[Complete list of US Zip codes](http://www.aggdata.com/free/zip-code)

[list of other free aggregated data](http://www.aggdata.com/free-data) downloadable as xls and csv.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use any old data I've got on harddrive already. I have some old budget calculations and whatnot. Otherwise it can't be that much work to whip up some useful sandbox data to play with. [Here are two tables](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0Arubax8NcAhBckU3X1NKVURZSU5hWFV2M1E5M1JTLVE&hl=en) of data with formulas and graphs that you should be able to grab and put into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try the US Census web site. For example, [here's a bunch of data on Georgia](http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/13000.html). At the bottom is a link to download it.